# JavaScript split string on first dash in string into 2 values

Tags: javascript

I need to split a string into 2 values, using the first "-" in the string, as the separator.

String example:

```
09/10/20  6:00 PM - All-Worn Camera Committee
```

I need to have:

```
arr[0] = 09/10/20  6:00 PM
arr[1] = All-Worn Camera Committee
```

Would it be possible to ask for an example on how to do this?

Many thanks,
Erasmo.

**UPDATE**

Arrrggghh!

It is messy, sometimes I have seen there can be 1, and there are instances in which more than 2 dashes, examples:

```
"09/11/20 12:00 PM - Food Policy Council  - Food Work Group" 
OR 
"09/10/20  6:00 PM - Body-Worn Review Committee"
```

Pretty much I need to separate the Meeting Date, and the Meeting Title, I thought that I could use the "dash" or " - " as delimiter, but there are strings that contain more than 2, 3 dashes.

Comment: Please show any attempt that you have made to solve this issue yourself.  You are expected to have made an attempt that we can then help you debug.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  Also review [ask]

Comment: Doesn't the `split()` method do what you want? It takes an optional `limit` argument, so you can tell it to stop after the first delimiter.

Comment: `split` with a 1imit` paramter is not a solution for the updated question - it  only limits the number of split strings returned in the array, not the number of splits that are made.  Try writing code that uses (string methods) `indexOf` to find the index of the first hyphen minus, and then `substring` twice, to obtain the leading and trailing parts of the input string separately. Ask about the resultant code if you can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the string `.split()` method. Just specify the character and max number of splits.

```js
var my_string = "09/10/20  6:00 PM - All-Worn Camera Committee"
var split_string = my_string.split("-", 1)

console.log(split_string[0])
```

[Split method reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String split method in Javascript.

```
let str = "09/10/20  6:00 PM - All-Worn Camera Committee";
str.split(" - "); //include spaces so you don't accidentally split the "All-Worn"
```

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: It is messy, sometimes I have seen there can be more than 2 dashes, example: "09/11/20 12:00 PM - Food Policy - Regional Food Sovereignty Work Group". Pretty much I need to separate the Meeting Date, and the Meeting Title, I thought that I could use the "dash" or " - " as delimiter, but there are strings that contain more than 2, 3 dashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split method:

```js
let str = '09/10/20  6:00 PM - All-Worn Camera Committee';

console.log(str.split(' - '))
```

Comment: There are string instances like: "09/11/20 12:00 PM - Food Policy Council  - Food Work Group" OR "09/10/20  6:00 PM - Body-Worn Review Committee"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript split() method. The returned value will be an array, containing the splitted values. In this case you have  2 "-" in the string. Then you have to add space so it won't split All-worn text.

```
<script>
var myString = "09/10/20 6:00 PM - All-Worn Camera Committee";
var stringArray = myString.split(" - ");

// then, loop through to display element of stringArray
for(var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++){
    document.write("<p>" + stringArray[i] + "</p>");
}
</script>
```

Comment: would it work if the string could also be: "09/11/20 12:00 PM - Food Policy - Regional Food Sovereignty Work Group". ??

Comment: @erasmocarlos this example will split the string into 3. The stringArray will have 3 elements. stringArray[0], stringArray[1], stringArray[2]